# Cancel auto spacing/new line using parbox

Tags: texmaker, parbox

I don't know why but with this code, Latex provide me a new line after each `\wedge` and some weird spaces after `\alpha` and `\notin`

```
$\rightarrow$= \parbox{5.5cm}{
$\{((s_1,s_2),\alpha,(s_1',s_2)) | \alpha \notin H \wedge (s_1,\alpha,s_1') \in \rightarrow 1 \} \cup$  \\ 
$\{((s_1,s_2),\alpha,(s_1,s_2')) | \alpha \notin H \wedge (s_2,\alpha,s_2') \in \rightarrow 2 \} \cup$  \\ 
$\{((s_1,s_2),\alpha,(s_1',s_2'))| \alpha \notin H \wedge (s_1,\alpha,s_1') \in \rightarrow 1 \cap (s_2,\alpha,s_2') \in \rightarrow 2 \}$
```

}

I would like to write it in only 4 lines and without these spaces while there is enough space to write it on one line.
[image: I would like to write it in only 4 lines and without these spaces]

I'm using the package `amsmath` (but i'm not sure it's related).

How can i do this? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a **full** minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need a \parbox for this?

Comment: I suppose that the 5.5cm forces the linebreaks.... just increase the width

Comment: I'm cleaning what I've written before in course and it was something like that, this was not with a  `\case` and before \parbox was working perfectly but yes idk why i didn't asked myself "why are the 5.5cm here? "... it was late in the evening, thanks @koleygr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like everybody else here, I do not know what you're after. Even worse, [my crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen, so I have to guess. Most likely this means that I will have to remove this, but I am wondering if you want to achieve something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\dots \rightarrow=\begin{dcases}
\{((s_1,s_2),\alpha,(s_1',s_2)) | \alpha \notin H \wedge (s_1,\alpha,s_1') \in \rightarrow 1 \} \cup{}  \\ 
\{((s_1,s_2),\alpha,(s_1,s_2')) | \alpha \notin H \wedge (s_2,\alpha,s_2') \in \rightarrow 2 \} \cup{} \\ 
\{((s_1,s_2),\alpha,(s_1',s_2'))| \alpha \notin H \wedge (s_1,\alpha,s_1') \in
\rightarrow 1 \cap (s_2,\alpha,s_2') \in \rightarrow 2 \}
\end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT***: Added `{}` at the end, big thanks to Bernard!

Comment: I guess the first two lines should end with `\cup {}` for a correct spacing.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! This is really just to find out what the OP wants and will be deleted anyway.

Comment: I'm using parbox instead of cases because in my course that i'm cleaning there is not any `{`. But this is working also. I have marked it as the answer because they were asking me to put a MWE and i guess this is the right format thanks! But now i'm wondering what the `\[` (line 3) `\]` (line 11) are doing in your exemple?

Comment: @Kokodelo, If your math is not inline (that I suppose it cant be inline -it would be to tall for a line-) then you have to use them inside `$$<math here>$$` or `\[<math here>\]`... with the second being preferred for many years in LaTeX (and not TeX) coding.

Comment: @Kokodelo `\[...\]` is a shortcut for `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}\, i.e. an unnumbered equation. You could also do `$\displaystyle ...$` if you do not want a line break, but I do not think that will give a good-looking result.